# NGINX 413 Error: Upload large files in Wordpress (HTTP Error)

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, server

I've trying to upload MP4 files into a Wordpress media but the 413 error stop's me. The limit of my life (in this immortal bug) is 100mb, more of that is the point to a beautiful HTTP ERROR.

My env have all in latest versions (PHP, NGINX, Ubuntu, FPM and FastCGI), in a digital ocean droplet.

My confs contains:

```
php.ini (FPM and CLI)

file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 700M
max_file_uploads = 20
post_max_size = 710M
max_execution_time = 3000
max_input_time = 6000
memory_limit = 700M

nginx.conf and "site".conf (http, server and location contex)

fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";
gzip_vary on;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_min_length 256;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon image/jpeg image/png image/jpg;
server_tokens off;
sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 5000;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
client_max_body_size 700M;
```

I've try to add this to NGINX:

```
client_body_timeout   300;
client_header_timeout 300;
send_timeout 300;
```

Not work.

After all of my searches, the error persists and I won't to see a exit to this error.

Please, anyone help me?

Comment: _“Note: For very large files, you may need to change value of client_body_timeout parameter. Default is 60s.”_ (https://easyengine.io/tutorials/php/increase-file-upload-size-limit/)

Comment: Thanks for reply @04FS. See my edit, please. This not working (i've try this before post).

Comment: Have you checked what the error log has to say?

Comment: Yes, no logs to this. (/var/log/nginx/error.log). Only in console i see the 413 error)

Comment: try client_body_timeout   3600;
client_header_timeout 3600;
send_timeout 3600; also dont forget to restart php-fpm and nginx

Comment: Thanks for reply @FlorinAndrei but, this not work. I've add this and restart all services but, the error persists.

Comment: Do you use cloudflare? Cloudflare or other service providers use some kind of upload limits!

Comment: @FlorinAndrei you are a life saver! THANKS MAN!!! This is the problem and I so sad with cloudflare because the error points to a problem in server (413 nginx) not a "cloudflare limit". THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

If do you use a CDN or similar service between client and server, see if this have limits to max upload files.

In my case, i've use cloudflare and it don't show this limitation in any place and, not show a clarify error.

However, thanks for all replys.

Answer (score 0):

If its a new Droplet, sometimes when you upload a local WordPress website to it, you need to change file permissions for www user. You might not have the permissions to do it.

So try

```
chown -Rf www-data.www-data /var/www/html/
```

change the path /html/ according to your server setup

Comment: Thanks for reply! This not solve my problem. I have all permissions and, the error is 413 (too large).